# Unable to increase the Session Variable timeout in .Net Application?

Tags: .net, session-timeout

My application is heavily dependent upon session variables. I am passing lots of ids through sessions e.g. `Session["RecordId"] = myID`. The problem is session gets expire in few minutes even tough I have increased the timeout of session variables. I have attempted to extend session expiry:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```

I also tried to increase the timeout using `IIS` and `Global.asax` file. Is there any other way or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if really need mode to be StateServer where  StateConnectionString

```
 <sessionState mode="StateServer"
  stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
  cookieless="false"
  timeout="20"/>
```

else you can use default mode value InProc

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```